# Replacement with long strings

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I was using gsub to replace parts of a long string from a text file, eg.

```
      str.gsub!(/#{str1}/){"#{updates}"}
```

When the string became long, ruby returned an error that the string is too long. How can I solve this problem?  Is there any substitute for gsub that can do the same work? As far as I know, gsub will produce a copy of the original data, which is inefficient.

Comment: Hard to tell what you're actually asking, but I suspect that it may work with `str.gsub! str1, updates`

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: A quick review of the source indicates that passing a string to `gsub` still builds a regex so that won't help. Have a look at `get_pat` in `string.c` if you're curious.

Comment: Yeah, looks like you're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `str1` is just a string rather than a regex fragment then you can do things like this:

```
str[str1] = updates
```

to replace the `str1` part of `str` with `updates` in place. For example:

```
>> s = 'Where is X house?'
=> "Where is X house?"
>> s['X'] = 'pancakes'
=> "pancakes"
>> s
=> "Where is pancakes house?"
```

You'd have to repeat that in a loop of some sort until you got an IndexError if you wanted to replace all the `str1`s in `str` though.

Regexes are great but your toolbox should have more than just a hammer.

BTW, if `str1` is supposed to be just a string, you should be use [`Regexp.escape`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) on it before interpolating it into a regex.